# Tool to convert Boost unit tests to Google Test (GTest) unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, boost, googletest, boost-test

Is anyone aware of a tool to automatically convert boost test unit tests to GTest? Lots of simple tests look like they could be automatically converted at the very least, saving a lot of time.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?